# pip install the minimum-impact historical package version

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

TLDR: I want the ability to `pip install` whichever version of a package will require the minimal changes to my currently installed versions.

Long version:

I support a pretty complex base container for geoscience research.
My users sometimes fork the environment to add a new package for their specific use-case.  The `pip install` of the new package often causes a cascade of upgrades, which inevitably breaks something.  `pip install --no-deps` is no help -- it just means the new package won't work, because it's missing dependencies.

What I always seem to end up doing is manually walking the version history of the new package, looking for a version that will cause minimum disturbance to my existing packages.

Is there any way of automatically finding this "minimal-disturbance" historical version of the new package?

Comment: What are you using to manage your base container?

Comment: @BeRT2me, I'm flexible.  The container is presently defined in an Ubuntu-based Dockerfile.  There's a global pyenv, and the requirements are installed into that with pip.  Most development uses pyenv and python-poetry.